# open (S, $fh) in perl

Tags: perl, file, semaphore

I came across some code on a thread that started like

`open (S, $SEMAPHORE) or die;`

I am unfamiliar with S used as a bareword.  What is it referring to?  There is no previous use higher in the code sample.

Comment: Ever used `STDIN`, `STDOUT` or `STDERR`? Those are preopened, but no different than `S`, `FILE`, or whatever else you want to call your file handle. Note that using globs instead of lexical variables is discouraged, though.

Answer (score 6):

Although it is not recommended, bareword filehandles are part of the language.  So it is not referring to anything, S is just the name they gave to that filehandle.

See http://perlmaven.com/open-files-in-the-old-way for discussion.

Comment: It's also bad practice in newer code, as lexical filehandles with 3 argument open are in almost every way superior.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the main disadvantage of bareword filehandles is that they are global.  Whereas with `open(my $fh, '<', $path)` the variable `$fh` is lexically scoped.